# how to search this field in Postgres for an array of characters

Tags: postgresql, array

I have a users table which is an `id`, `name`, and `tags`. I'd like to search tags for a specific piece of text. How would I do do this?

```
id                      | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass) 
name                    | character varying           | 
tags                    | character varying[]         | default '{}'::character varying[]
```

How would I search for a tag like "skiing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from the_table
where 'skiing' = any (tags);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/BDF4617